# Using adjective as adverb in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

This is a rather technical sentence, including two adjectives which I want to use as adverbs. I would like to know if I used them properly or not - and if not, how can I say it better?

> *We simulate the way a human user scans a web page **bottom-up or top-down** to find his data of interest.*

Comment: Your *example* usage is fine, but I'll just tweak the rest of your text to suit.

Comment: Far less technical than your nested context scenarios :)  I'd suggest you change "human user" to "person".  Then it will sound as though your text had been written by a human writer.

Comment: It would make for better readability if we set aside the adjective-adverbial issues and chuck the hyphen as well: "We simulate the way a human user scans a web page bottom up or top down to find his data of interest." -- Why complicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is fine. *Top-down* and *bottom-up* aren't inherently adjectives; they're locative<sup>†</sup> expressions, which can be employed adjectivally, adverbially and even nominally as needed.

> ADJECTIVAL: I'm a firm proponent of top-down programming.
>   ADVERBIAL:   I usually program top-down.
>   NOMINAL:      Top-down is my usual programming method.

---

<sup>†</sup> Be warned: this is my own idiosyncratic use of *locative*, which embraces expressions designating paths and targets as well as 'locations' in the ordinary sense. If someone wants to suggest a better term I'll be happy to entertain it.

Comment: See also: My comment at OP.